gaia id not found for email, Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1
I try to use  Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 at my c# project
I registered google cloud, added a project
made gcloud init and created local ADC wile with
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account xxx@gmail.com
when I debug below code, at client.SynthesizeSpeech call it is giving error
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error:"{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email xxx@gmail.com",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email xxx.com",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
...

var client = new TextToSpeechClientBuilder
{
    GrpcAdapter = RestGrpcAdapter.Default
}.Build();


SynthesisInput input = new SynthesisInput
{
    Text = "Hello"
};

VoiceSelectionParams voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
{
    LanguageCode = "en-US",
    SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Male
};

AudioConfig audioConfig = new AudioConfig
{
    AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    SampleRateHertz = 22050,
};
SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);
using (Stream output = File.Create("c:/temp/sample.wav"))
{
    // response.AudioContent is a ByteString. This can easily be converted into
    // a byte array or written to a stream.
    response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
}


How can I get rid of this error.

Gaia is Google's internal identity management service.
Service Account email addresses take various forms but you'd customarily expect to see something of the form {account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com; you cannot use a Gmail account as a Service Account email and this is why you receive this obscure error.
See use Service Account impersonation for a comprehensive guide.
